# decode string algorithm implementation for advice

Tags: python, algorithm

Working on below algorithm puzzle to decode a string containing numbers into characters. Post full problem statement and reference code. Actually I referred a few solutions, and it seems all solutions I found decode from back to the front, and I think decode from front to end should also be fine, just wondering if any special benefits or considerations why for this problem, it is better to decode from back to front? Thanks.

A message containing letters from A-Z is being encoded to numbers using the following mapping:

'A' -> 1
'B' -> 2
...
'Z' -> 26
Given an encoded message containing digits, determine the total number of ways to decode it.

For example,
Given encoded message "12", it could be decoded as "AB" (1 2) or "L" (12).

The number of ways decoding "12" is 2.

```
public class Solution {
    public int numDecodings(String s) {
        int n = s.length();
        if (n == 0) return 0;

        int[] memo = new int[n+1];
        memo[n]  = 1;
        memo[n-1] = s.charAt(n-1) != '0' ? 1 : 0;

        for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--)
            if (s.charAt(i) == '0') continue;
            else memo[i] = (Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i,i+2))<=26) ? memo[i+1]+memo[i+2] : memo[i+1];

        return memo[0];
    }
}
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 2):

There will be no difference whether you decode the string from front-to-back or back-to-front if you break it into sub-strings and store their results.

This implements front-to-back approach:

```
def decode_string(st):
    result_dict = {st[0]:1}

    for i in xrange(2,len(st)+1):
        if int(st[i-1]) == 0:
            if int(st[i-2]) not in [1,2]:
                return "Not possible to decode"

            result_dict[st[:i]] = 0

        else:
            result_dict[st[:i]] = result_dict[st[:i-1]]

        if int(st[i-2:i]) < 27 and st[i-2] != '0':
            result_dict[st[:i]] = result_dict[st[:i]] + result_dict.get(st[:i-2],1)

    return result_dict[st]

print decode_string("125312")
```

`result_dict` contains all the possibilities for incremental sub-strings. Initialize with first character

Special check for '0' character because the only acceptable values for 0 are 10 and 20. So break from the loop if input contains something else

Then for each index check whether the combination with the previous index is a character (combination < 27) or not. If true, add the result of string upto index-2 to it.

Store the result of each incremental sub-string in the dictionary

**Result:**

The `result_dict` contains values like this:

```
{'12': 2, '12531': 3, '1': 1, '125312': 6, '125': 3, '1253': 3}
```

So `result_dict[st]` gives the required answer

**Using Lists** is a better idea

```
def decode_string(st):
    result_list = [1]
    for i in xrange(2,len(st)+1):
        if int(st[i-1]) == 0:
            if int(st[i-2]) not in [1,2]:
                return "Not possible to decode"

            result_list.append(0)

        else:
            result_list.append(result_list[i-2])

        if int(st[i-2:i]) < 27 and st[i-2] != '0':
            if i>2:
                result_list[i-1] = result_list[i-1] + result_list[i-3]
            else:
                result_list[i-1] = result_list[i-1] + 1
    print result_list
    return result_list[-1]

print decode_string("125312")
```

Comment: Thanks Temi, great answer. One thing I do not quite understand is for this line, `result_dict[st[:i]] = 0` when `int(st[i-1]) == 0`. For example, string 210xxx, I think the number of results ends with `str[2] == 0`, (with prefix substring 210) should not be zero?

Comment: BTW, Temi, when `int(st[i-1]) == 0`, both statements `result_dict[st[:i]] = 0` and `result_dict[st[:i]] = result_dict[st[:i-1]]` will be executed, and latter will overwrite for former? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, another quick question is, for the dictionary, `result_dict`, what is the logical meaning for key and value? Why not just use a list (means ends with i-1 th character, what are the available combinations)? :)

Comment: @LinMa Second else condition is not wrong but seems redundant. because when st[i-1] == 0 it should satisfy the (< 27) if condition or the string is in wrong format. Nice catch

Comment: @LinMa Dictionary lookups are faster than lists but in this case we don't need the results for substrings. So using lists is better as it will use less memory. In that case you need to store the results with `list index` same as `string end index`. Included the lists part in the answer

Comment: Thanks Termi, one more confusion is, in my original posted code, which iterates from back to front, when an element is 0, its related result is 0 -- refer to this line `if (s.charAt(i) == '0') continue;`. But when using your code to iterate from front to back, I debugged when an element is zero, the related result is not zero (I tried sample `2101` for example). I debugged both implementation, and it seems both are correct. Wondering if you have any comments about why iteration direction results in different result when met with number 0? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa I am storing the results of sub-strings with `list index` same as `string end index`.  So for `2101` result list is `[1,2,1,1]` that means `2 - 1 way` , `21 - 2 ways (2,1 & 21)` , `210 - 1 way (2,10)`, `2101 - 1 way (2,10,1)` . So for '2101' when the character is '0' you must have got '1' . I hope now your doubt is clarified :)

Comment: @LinMa So does the list implementation works as you expected ??

Comment: Thanks Termi, I debugged your both versions and it works fine. I also debugged the original version I posted (which traverse from back). I fully understand in your solution, when met with an element with `0`, its related result is not zero. But my confusion is, in the backward traverse version I posted, when an element is 0, its related result is 0 -- refer to this line if `(s.charAt(i) == '0') continue;`, just curious why they are treated so differently from backward and front traverse, and surprising why both have the right results?

Comment: And Termi, if you could help to comment on the puzzle, it will be great. :)